# Using a few $parents for $broadcast

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent" ng-repeat="parent in parents">
        <div class="child" ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
            <div class="grandchild" ng-repeat="grandchild in child.grandchild">
```

Now, `.grandchild` wants to `$broadcast` something to another `.grandchild`. This can simply be done via `$rootScope.$broadcast('SOMETHING');`.

But I don't want to use `$rootScope`, so that $digest doesn't run through everything. Instead, I want to do something like `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$broadcast('SOMETHING')`.

While this is ugly, but in the end, this will go through less elements, since it will only travel through the scope `grandparent`

Are there any other suggestions? (For the purpose of this example, say that I have to use `broadcast`. So please don't comment saying that I shouldn't use this)

Comment: You could actually try a pub/sub mechanism. Add couple of methods subscribe/publish on the rootscope.. scope inheritance will take those mthods available in any childscopes (except for isolated scope). and just use them for communication. You could either add this on the rootscope or create a pubsub service, inject them wherever you need...

Comment: @PSL can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generally avoid attaching event listeners to individual scopes.

An efficient way to do what you want is to use `$rootScope.$on` and `$rootScope.$emit` (not `$broadcast`). The difference between `$emit` and `$broadcast` is that `$emit` does not propagate downwards, therefore it only effects those who are directly subscribed.

Comment: sorry but the $emit propagate only upward

Comment: @Polochon, what @TinSnail actually works really well. You `$emit` on `$rootScope` (so only `$rootScope` hears it), and then you listen on the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

Firing AngularJS Events does not trigger a call to `$digest` anywhere. It will only call all registered subscribers. It doesn't matter if you `$broadcast` in the current `$scope` or the `$rootScope`. The only thing calling a digest is the directive (maybe a ngClick) which executes your code which fires the event (with broadcast or emit), because the the directive will call `$apply`. `$apply` now calls `$digest` on the ... yes `$rootScope` ! You can't prevent this behaviour.

So, it doesn't matter what you're doing, you're most probably starting a `$digest` cycle from the `$rootScope`. And as long as you're not having serious performance issues, you should stick with that and don't try to pre-optimize your code.